# Circular property reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of the color selector dialog in MS Paint.  I have a ViewModel for the dialog that has 3 properties.

- public Color SelectedColor

  - this is the selected color
  - I bind this to the background of a Border element that displays the currently selected color
- public double SelectorLeft

  - the left location of the selector in the custom color area
  - I bind this to the selector's left value.  The selector is an element within a Canvas
  - The canvas's x axis is the hue
- public double SelectorTop

  - the top location of the selector in the custom color area
  - I bind this to the selector's top value.  The selector is an element within a Canvas
  - The canvas's y axis is the saturation

The problem is that they're all related to each other.  When I select a color from the predefined colors area, I need to update SelectedColor, which in turn should update SelectorLeft and SelectorTop so the selector in the custom color area is in the correct place.  Also, when I move the selector around in the custom color area, I need to update SelectedLeft and SelectedTop, which should both update SelectedColor.  These relations cause stack overflows.

(Ha!, a stack overflow problem listed on StackOverflow)

Is there another approach I can take to solve this that removes the dependence of one property on another.  Or maybe define different properties to bind to?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Make two of the properties (Left, Top) read-only, and convert all inputs to the third form (e.g. a new SelectedColor) in order to set a new value.
- Make all the properties read only and instead use SetXXX methods to set a new value (which causes one or more of the 3 properties to change). I always recommend making properties as simple as possible, with minimal side-effects - setting one property should never cause other property values in the class to change. So a SetXXX method makes the side effect clear, and eliminates the circular references between the proeprties themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Don't raise the property changed event if the value is the same as the current value. This should prevent the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make two event methods:

UpdateSelectColor - MouseClick event method when you select pre-defined

1. Update SelectedColor values
2. Update SelectorLeft values
3. Update SelectorTop values

MoveSelector - When you move selector

1. Update SelectedColor values
2. Update SelectorLeft values
3. Update SelectorTop values